# Stock s8 wont play notification sounds

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, stock-android, ringtone, vibration

Here i got exonys version of samsung galaxy s8 64 GB running with android 7.0 stock rom.

I have set my notification settings to sound and vibrate. Many times when a message arrives , SMS or wapp , my phone would just vibrate for a fraction of a second and either won't play notification sound or play it for less than half a second.

What should happen , that happens occasionally , is vibration and notification tone should play for atleast 1 second (it did on my old s3).

Also it gets worse when phone is on sleep mode , you might get barely a millisecond of vibration and no sound.

It's annoying and requires me to manually check the phone multiple times a day to make sure i didn't miss any important messages.

Comment: You'll have to configure a third party alert for notifications, set longer notification sounds and hoping you haven't activated priority mode by any chance and also ensure no app is overriding that. Like the truecaller ring silently setting of blocking

Comment: @ThallyAce I have priority mode enabled should that be a problem

Comment: Maybe if it never notifies you upon certain numbers or even all numbers if adressbook sync is experiencing trouble hence not serving names to call or sometimes messages. Sometimes uneven behavior occur. But meanwhile disable priority mode and try it and see what happens